# How to Exclude Application Definition from Import in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex

I need to have different values in substitution strings in DEV and PROD. How do I prevent overwriting the substitution strings when updating PROD. DEV and PROD are in separate databases.

I don't see how to exclude the application definitions in build options.

Is there a better way to meet this requirement?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I see it, substitution strings are application items defined as constants. Only use them for strings that are always the same in any deployment instance of the app. As soon as the value needs to be changeable (for example dev has different value than prod), use application items instead.

If you insist on doing this with build options then this is an option:

- Set the values of the application items using a computation or an application process (this is for for production).
- Create a 2nd set of computations or an app process with a sequence higher than the sequence of the one above (so this will override the original values) and set a build option on those (exclude on export).

That way, when you export the app, only the first set of computations / app process will be included.

However, my preference is to configure this in the database and have a settings table that has a record indicating the status of the environment (prod/dev/stage/uat) and store the strings in a custom messages table (one record per app status/application item) . In an application process or computation get the value of the application items. The reason I prefer this is that the app doesn't need to know if it is dev or prod, but the database should. This option has a couple of challenges if the same database and schema is used for prod and dev.

Comment: Implemented the database solution. Works great. Thanks for the quick, accurate and detailed response.